# como gerar webview dentro do react

Tags: react

Ola eu estou construindo um portfloio para min, me deparei com a seguinte questao, quando eu uso a
api do github para fazer um map meus projetos, eles tem a opcao de

```
"homepage": "https://calc-iphone.nomedorprovedor.app",
```

e isso realmente vai para o site que fiz deploy porem estou a procura de gerar um thub ou um previw para que fique no meu projeto de forta dinaminca

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxVsH.png)

eu ja tentei o react-thumn

Comment: Se for um problema no deploy a postagem não cabe neste site, mas se for na parte do desenvolvimento em si, é importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.